# How To Open Several XML Files In WinForms C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Good Day, I Need to Deserialize Different XML Files In My Windows Forms Application, It Should Work Like The Following.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
So I have Tried So Much Alternatives, But This Is The Code That Is The Closest To My Goal.

```
    `private OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void ImportIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IfSound();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Analytica Files (*.analy) |*.analy";
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var Path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                Settings.Default.FileList.Add(file);
                Settings.Default.Save();
                //Settings.Default.Upgrade();
            }
            //XmlSerializer XS = new 
            //XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Information>));
            //StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Path);
            //Information i;
            //var input = XS.Deserialize(Reader);
            //Settings.Default.Counter++;
            //Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Found In File");
        }
    }
    foreach (string TheFile in Settings.Default.FileList)
        {
            Reminders.TaskUC Task = new Reminders.TaskUC();
            Point TP = new Point();
            Task.Name = "Task" + Settings.Default.Counter.ToString();
            TP.Y = 1;
            int Add = 300;
            int Result = Start;
            int Distance = 100;
            Control Last = Controls[Controls.Count - 1];
            TP.X = Last.Location.X + Distance;
            if (Settings.Default.FileList.Count == 1)
            {
                TP.X = 300;
            }
            Size PanelWidth = new Size();
            PanelWidth.Width = ReminderPanel.Width + 300;
            PanelWidth.Height = ReminderPanel.Height;
            Task.Location = TP;
            this.Controls.Add(Task);
            ReminderPanel.Size = PanelWidth;
            ReminderPanel.Controls.Add(Task);
            XmlSerializer XS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Information>));
            FileStream Read = new FileStream(TheFile, FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            Information i = new Information();
            XS.Deserialize(Read);
            Task.TitleBox.Text = i.Title1;
         }

            This is the class code:
             public class Information
{
       private string Title;
       private string Description;
       private DateTime Date;
       private DateTime Hour;
       private bool Check;
       public string Title1
    {
        get { return Title; }
        set { Title = value; }
    }

    public string Description2
    {
        get { return Description; }
        set { Description = value; }
    }

    public DateTime Date3
    {
        get { return Date; }
        set { Date = value; }
    }

    public DateTime Hour4
    {
        get { return Hour; }
        set { Hour = value; }
    }
    public bool Check5
    {
        get { return Check; }
        set { Check = value;}
    }
public class SaveXML
{
    public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer SR = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        TextWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
        SR.Serialize(Writer, obj);
        Writer.Close();
    } `
```

When This Line Runs,
    `XS.Deserialize(Read);`
  The App Stops, And Displays The Following Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error in the XML Document (2, 2).' 
>   Inner Exception.
>   InvalidOperationException: Doesn´t Expect .
>   (Sometimes It Displays (0, 0). Instead Of (2, 2).)

**Edit**
This is My XML File Code, Curiously, the another XML Files are void, like they have nothing inside, this, have this data inside:
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Title1>12</Title1>
    <Description2>Description</Description2>
    <Date3>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Date3>
    <Hour4>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Hour4>
    </Information>`

Comment: The error message tells you that there is a problem with your XML document.  Can you post that?

Comment: Ok @BJMyers Just Wait A Minute

Comment: maybe there's a discrepancy between your file and your class

Comment: Post an xml that doesn't work along with the one the does.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine with:

```
XS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
```

It looks like you changed the type you were deserializing before you changed your XML to match:

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Information>));
```

You need to change your XML file to be this and it should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfInformation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Information>
      <Title1>12</Title1>
      <Description2>Description</Description2>
      <Date3>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Date3>
      <Hour4>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Hour4>
  </Information>
</ArrayOfInformation>
```

Comment: The error disappeared, but, it doesn't deserialize even one file.